# Running two docker containers in "sidecar" mode with Jenkinsfile

Tags: python, selenium, docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have to run two docker containers in sidecar mode. I spent a couple of days trying to implement the correct pipeline, but I'm in despair now, because none of my ideas actually work.

First, I've read this block [Running sidecar containers](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/#running-sidecar-containers)

It's implement the approach inside the *node* {} block. Here's how my pipeline looks now:

```
pipeline {
agent any

options {
    disableConcurrentBuilds()
}

stages {
    stage("Obtain images") {
        steps {
            script {
                    writeFile(file: './ui-tests/env.yaml', text: "environment:\n  # dev or stage\n  type: dev\n  lang: en\n")
                    withDockerRegistry([credentialsId: 'my-hub', url: 'https://myhub.hub']) {
                        def selena = docker.image('myhub.hub/selenium-dev:latest')
                        def uirun = docker.image('myhub.hub/ui-shell-runner:latest')
                        selena.pull()
                        uirun.pull()
                    }

            }
        }
    }

    stage("Run tests") {
       steps {
        node('pyrunner') { 
                docker.image('myhub.hub/selenium-dev').withRun('-e JAVA_OPTS=-Xmx1024m') { test ->
                    docker.image('myhub.hub/selenium-dev').inside("--link ${test.id}:se") {
                        sh 'pwd'
                    }

                    docker.image('myhub.hub/ui-shell-runner:latest').inside("--link ${test.id}:se") {
                            sh 'cd ui-tests ; pwd ; nose2 -v --attribute desktop-site,type=smoke'
                        }
                }
        }
        }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the idea. First container with selenium myhub.hub/selenium-dev - running in background, second container myhub.hub/ui-shell-runner contains *nose2* utility that utilizing the first one. I tried to implement *node*, tried to remove it completely and move my code into *steps*, I tried to remove everything and run my containers via *sh 'docker container run ...'* (that's not good, though). None of my ideas actually work as I expect. And listed pipeline crashing  with

```
    WorkflowScript: 28: Expected a symbol @ line 28, column 6.
                    docker.image('myhub.hub/selenium-dev').withRun('-e JAVA_OPTS=-Xmx1024m') { test ->

WorkflowScript: 28: Arguments to "error" must be explicitly named. @ line 28, column 6.
                    docker.image('myhub.hub/selenium-dev').withRun('-e JAVA_OPTS=-Xmx1024m') { test ->
```

I'm out of ideas. What I gonna do next?

Answer (score 3):

Here's the code that works for me. Thanks to Denis Khokhryakov for his help and advice! In this example "se" - is the dns name of the first selenium container as well that we can use in second client container to connect.

```
pipeline {
agent any

options {
    disableConcurrentBuilds()
}

stages {
    stage("Obtain images") {
        steps {
            script {
                writeFile(file: './ui-tests/env.yaml', text: "environment:\n  # dev or stage\n  type: dev\n  lang: en\n")
                withDockerRegistry([credentialsId: 'my-hub', url: 'https://myhub.hub']) {
                    def selena = docker.image('myhub.hub/selenium-dev:latest')
                    def uirun = docker.image('myhub.hub/ui-shell-runner:latest')
                    selena.pull()
                    uirun.pull()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    stage("Run tests") {
        steps {
            script { 
                docker.image('myhub.hub/selenium-dev').withRun('-e JAVA_OPTS=-Xmx1024m') { test ->
                    docker.image('myhub.hub/selenium-dev').inside("--link ${test.id}:se") {
                        sh 'pwd'
                    }

                    docker.image('myhub.hub/ui-shell-runner:latest').inside("--link ${test.id}:se") {
                        sh 'cd ui-tests ; pwd ; nose2 -v --attribute desktop-site,type=smoke'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}